# display new Indian rupee symbol instead of Rs. in .net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, currency, tablesorter, uiculture

In my .net MVC Web application I am using 
`<globalization culture="en-IN" uiCulture="en-IN" />` to for Indian currency and date.

But problem is that it displays `Rs. 2,000.00` but I want it to display [image]2,000.00

For displaying purpose I can simply use the new rupee image wherever I want. 
But what to do for `tablesorter`. In `tablesorter` I want to display this new symbol. Because with the old symbol `Rs. 2,000.00` it consider it as string and thus results in wrong sorting order. Like:-

```
Rs. 70,000.00
Rs. 50,000.00
Rs. 1,00,000.00
Rs. 10,000.00
Rs. 1,000.00
Rs. 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show image in place of Text(Rs.), this is one way to solve your problem..

Comment: I tried that... But I don't want to use that. I want Rupee foradian symbol by default for all currency datatypes as it shows $ and others.

Comment: so in that case also , you can create helper in mvc and in that using formatter return image + text..so every time it displays currency in way you like..

Answer (score 0):

I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/599/) with table cells that look like this:

```
<td><i>Rs.</i> 70,000.00</td>
```

you can use css to hide the `<i>` and/or add a background image.

then use this custom parser, and initialize the table like this:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'rupee',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        s = $(cell).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType === 3; }).text();
        return s.replace(/[\s,]/g,'');
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function () {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            5: { sorter: 'rupee' }
        }
    });
});
```